# find a point on a line segment so that it is at a certain distance from an arbitrary point in 3D

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, 3d

let's say there is **3 points** in 3D **$p0$ , $p1$ , $p2$** , $l = p2-p1$ forms the line segment
and $p0$ is like isolated on its own. how can I find a point $q$ on $l$ that is away from $p0$ such that $||p0-q|| = d$ ? ($d$ is any distance)

my attempt :

$q = p1+s(p2-p1) = p1+sl$ for  $0 =< s =< 1$
now $||p0-p1+sl|| = d $ ? I'm stuck here

I know that terms like **s** are revealed with dotProduct equations but I can't
seem to find a meaningful one here, so how to find **s** essentially? Ho and every variable is known but s of course

[here is a figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7vVS.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that $p_{0}=(y_{1}, y_{2}, y_{3})$, $p_{1}=(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ and $l=(z_{1}, z_{1}, z_{3})$

Call $v$ the vector $v = p_{0}-p_{1}-sl$, then $v=(y_{1}-x_{1}-sz_{1}, y_{2}-x_{2}-sz_{2}, y_{3}-x_{2}-sz_{3})$

You must solve $v^2 = d^2$, or $v \cdot v = d^2$. Just apply the dot product of $v$ with itself and you will get a second degree equation in $s$ (note that every other variable is known). The trick here is to square.

You will get $(y_{1}-x_{1}-sz_{1})^2 + (y_2-x_2-sz_2)^2 + (y_3-x_3-sz_3)^2 = d^2$, which you only have to develop, giving you:

$(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2) s^2 + 2(x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + x_3z_3 - y_1z_1 - y_2z_2 - y_3z_3)s + (y_1^2+x_1^2+y_2^2+x_2^2+y_3^2+x_3^2 - 2y_1x_1 - 2y_2x_2 - 2y_3x_3 -d^2) = 0$

Comment: tried to reach the equation in s but failed , suggestions ?  \n f

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the polynomial in $s$. Note that there are usually two solutions unless the $d$ is the distance from $p_0$ to the line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach the problem, step by step.

Let's say the line segment is between points $\vec{p}_1 = ( x_1 , y_1 , z_1)$ and $\vec{p}_2 = ( x_2 , y_2 , z_2 )$. If we parametrize that using $s$, $0 \le s \le 1$, we have
$$\vec{p}(s) = (1-s)\vec{p}_1 + s\vec{p}_2 = \vec{p}_1 + s \left ( \vec{p}_2 - \vec{p}_1 \right ) \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
(By the way, I almost always parametrise my line segments that way: it seems to be a good starting point in general for this kind of problems. Note that $\vec{p}(0) = \vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}(1) = \vec{p}_2$.)

We want to find the point $\vec{p}(s)$ that is at distance $d$ from point $\vec{p}_0 = ( x_0 , y_0 , z_0 )$, i.e. solve $s$ from
$$\left\lVert \vec{p}(s) - \vec{p}_0 \right\rVert = d \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
Because both sides are nonnegative, we can square both sides. The above is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{\left(\vec{p}(s) - \vec{p}_0 \right)\cdot\left(\vec{p}(s) - \vec{p}_0 \right)} = d$$
which when squared, is
$$\left(\vec{p}(s) - \vec{p}_0 \right)\cdot\left(\vec{p}(s) - \vec{p}_0 \right) = d^2 \tag{3}\label{NA3}$$
which expands to
$$\left( (1-s) x_1 + s x_2 - x_0 \right)^2 + \left( (1-s) y_1 + s y_2 - y_0 \right)^2 + \left( (1-s) z_1 + s z_2 - z_0 \right)^2 = d^2 \tag{4}\label{NA4}$$
Since we are interested in $s$, we rewrite that as a polynomial in $s$, collecting the factors of powers of $s$. We get
$$\begin{array}{rl}
\left( (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2 \right) s^2 & + \\
2 \left( (x_1-x_0)(x_2-x_1) + (y_1-y_0)(y_2-y_1) + (z_1-z_0)(z_2-z_1) \right) s & + \\
(x_1-x_0)^2 + (y_1-y_0)^2 + (z_1-z_0)^2 - d^2 & = 0
\end{array} \tag{5}\label{NA5}$$
which is a simple [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

If we rewrite $\eqref{NA5}$ using
$$\begin{array}{l}
C_2 = (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2 \\
C_1 = 2\left( (x_1-x_0)(x_2-x_1) + (y_1-y_0)(y_2-y_1) + (z_1-z_0)(z_2-z_1) \right) \\
C_0 = (x_1-x_0)^2 + (y_1-y_0)^2 + (z_1-z_0)^2 - d^2 \end{array}$$
then the equation to solve is
$$C_2 s^2 + C_1 s + C_0 = 0$$
and therefore:

- If $C_1^2 \gt 4 C_2 C_0$, there are two possible solutions $s$:
  $$s = \frac{-C_1 \pm \sqrt{C_1^2 - 4 C_2 C_0}}{2 C_2} \tag{6a}\label{NA6a}$$
- If $C_1^2 = 4 C_2 C_0$, there is one possible solution $s$:
  $$s = \frac{-C_1}{2 C_2} \tag{6b}\label{NA6b}$$
- Otherwise, $C_1^2 \lt 4 C_2 C_0$, and there are no solutions.

But do note that only $0 \le s \le 1$ are on the line segment. You do need to verify each possible $s$ to find the point. When you do find such an $s$, substitute that $s$ into $\eqref{NA1}$ to get the actual point (that is exactly at distance $d$ from $\vec{p}_0$, but on the line segment between $\vec{p}_1$ and $\vec{p}_2$).

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, what you’re trying to find is the intersection of the line segment with a sphere of radius $d$ centered at $p_0$. One approach, described in other answers, is to parameterize the the line segment and then develop and solve a quadratic equation in the parameter. It’s also possible to crank out the intersections directly, without having to solve any equations.

It’s convenient to work in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) to do some parts of this. Since I’ll be jumping back and forth between homogeneous and (inhomogeneous) Cartesian coordinates, I’ll use boldface names to indicate homogeneous coordinate vectors and boldface names with a tilde above for inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates.

Start by finding the nearest point on the line $\mathbf l = \overline{\mathbf p_1\mathbf p_2}$ to $\mathbf p_0$. This can be done by finding the intersection of the line with the plane through $\mathbf p_0$ that’s perpendicular to $\mathbf l$. Let $\tilde{\mathbf v}=\tilde{\mathbf p}_2-\tilde{\mathbf p}_1$ be a direction vector of $\mathbf l$. The plane through $\mathbf p_0$ with this normal vector can be represented by the homogeneous vector $\mathbf\pi = \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{\mathbf v}^T; -\tilde{\mathbf v}^T\tilde{\mathbf p}_0 \end{bmatrix}$, i.e., $\tilde{\mathbf v}$ with the negative of its dot product with $\tilde{\mathbf p}_0$ appended. The components of this vector are just the coefficients of an equation $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz+d=0$ of the plane. The intersection of this plane with $\mathbf l$ can be found by multiplying $\mathbf\pi$ by the Plücker matrix of the line: $$\mathbf q = (\mathbf p_1\mathbf p_2^T-\mathbf p_2\mathbf p_1^T)\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf p_2^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf p_1-(\mathbf p_1^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf p_2.$$ In terms of the above equation of the plane $\mathbf\pi$, this expression says to plug $\tilde{\mathbf p}_2$ into $f$ and multiply $\mathbf p_1$ by the result, and vice-versa, and then take the difference of the resulting vectors. After converting this back into inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates $\tilde{\mathbf q}$ by dividing through by the last component of $\mathbf q$, finding the two intersection points is a straightforward application of the Pythagorean theorem: the intersections of $\mathbf l$ with the sphere are located at a distance of $$d' = \sqrt{d^2 - \|\tilde{\mathbf q}-\tilde{\mathbf p}_0\|^2} = \sqrt{d^2-(\tilde{\mathbf q}-\tilde{\mathbf p}_0)\cdot(\tilde{\mathbf q}-\tilde{\mathbf p}_0)}$$ along the line in either direction from $\tilde{\mathbf q}$, i.e., they are the points $$\tilde{\mathbf q} \pm d'{\tilde{\mathbf v}\over\|\tilde{\mathbf v}\|}.$$ If the quantity under the radial is negative, that means that the line segment is too far away from $\mathbf p_0$ and there’s no solution.

You’ll still need to check that these points are actually within the line segment, just as with the “solve a quadratic equation” approach, but that can be done with some range checks. You can, of course, use the normalized direction vector ${\tilde{\mathbf v}\over\|\tilde{\mathbf v}\|}$ to form $\mathbf\pi$, since a homogeneous vector can be multiplied by a non-zero constant without affecting what it represents.

For example, take $\tilde{\mathbf p}_0=(0,-3,-1)^T$, $\tilde{\mathbf p}_1=(3,2,5)^T$, $\tilde{\mathbf p}_2=(-1,0,2)^T$ and $d=5$. Then $\tilde{\mathbf v}=(-4,-2,-3)^T$ and $\mathbf\pi=[-4,-2,-3,-9]^T$. This gives $$\begin{align} \mathbf q &= ([-1,0,2,1]\cdot[-4,-2,-3,-9])[3,2,5,1]^T-([3,2,5,1]^T\cdot[-1,0,2,1])[-1,0,2,1]^T \\
&= [-73,-22,25,29]^T, \end{align}$$ and so $$\tilde{\mathbf q} \approx (-2.517,-0.759,0.862).$$ From this we get $d' \approx 3.189$, therefore the intersections of $\mathbf l$ with the sphere are $(-4.886,-1.943,-0.915)$ and $(-0.148,0.426,2.638)$. The former is out of range for the line segment, but the latter is not, so in this example there’s one solution.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot guys!
I followed the path of @ElieLouis (by the way you made some mistake at the beginning tho) , and used the quadratic formula to be done with it. Also @amd your solution seemed the most elegant , but I couldn't use it because of the extra w coordinates , never had experience with it and I didn't understand your method fully either..

$z$ is the line segment $(p2-p1)~$ , $x,y,z~$ are respective components; $a,b,c~$ are the terms of the quadratic(pre-computed).

$a = z·z$

$b = 2(z_xp1_x - z_xp0_x + z_yp1_y - z_yp0_y + z_zp1_z - z_zp0_z)$

$c =  
p0_x^2 + p1_x^2 + p0_y^2 + p1_y^2 + p0_z^2 + p1_z^2 - 2p0_xp1_x - 2p0_yp1_y - 2p0_zp1_z - d^2$

for $~~p0 = (1, 0, 3)
, p1 = (0, 0, 2)
, p2 = (2, 0, 0)$ and $d = 1.8$

$s = 0.393700393701~~or~~-0.393700393701$

verifying:
||($p1+sz)- p0|| = 1.8$ and that happens to be true.